# Proof verification of limit of a sequence in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Please let me know if my proof is correct.

> Let,
> $$
> X(n)=\begin {cases} 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}\\ 2 & \text{if $n$ is even.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Prove that $X(n)$ is divergent.

**Proof.**
For the sake of contradiction, let us assume that $X(n)$ converges to some $x\in\mathbb R$.
If so, then for a given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ $K\in\mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \geq K$,
$|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. Thus, if we take odd  values for $n$ then we get that $x_n=0$ and thus $|-x|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we see that $|-x|=0$ and thus, $x=0$. But if $x=0$ then for even values of $n$, $2<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. This is obviously absurd since we can choose $0<\epsilon<2$. Thus, $X(n)$ is divergent.

Comment: It looks good to me, but I would suggest explicitly stating that in the even $n$ case, you have $|2 - x| = |2 - 0| = 2 < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. I would also state somewhere that you're using the result that every subsequence of $(X(n))$, if $(X(n))$ converges, converges to the same limit.

Comment: thank you.  I will edit it now.

Comment: Simpler (for me) approach: Assume there exists a limit. Take epsilon to be e.g. 1. But for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, |X(n) - X(n+1)| = 2. Thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: another approach: take $\varepsilon=1$. let $N$ be a natural number. take $n$ even and $m$ odd, both $n,m$ larger than $N$. then $|x_n-x_m|=2>1=\varepsilon$ so the sequence is not Cauchy.